# How to receive message via POST from Mailgun in NodeJS?

Tags: node.js, mailgun

Im trying to set up a API endpoint for messages which are being forwarded from mailgun.

In their doc they have a example Django Code which looks like this:

```
# Handler for HTTP POST to http://myhost.com/messages for the route defined above
def on_incoming_message(request):
     if request.method == 'POST':
         sender    = request.POST.get('sender')
         recipient = request.POST.get('recipient')
         subject   = request.POST.get('subject', '')

         body_plain = request.POST.get('body-plain', '')
         body_without_quotes = request.POST.get('stripped-text', '')
         # note: other MIME headers are also posted here...

         # attachments:
         for key in request.FILES:
             file = request.FILES[key]
             # do something with the file

     # Returned text is ignored but HTTP status code matters:
     # Mailgun wants to see 2xx, otherwise it will make another attempt in 5 minutes
     return HttpResponse('OK')
```

Now in my Express App I got this piece of code:

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();

// @route   POST api/inbox
// @desc    HTTP handler for messages from mailgun
// @access  public
router.post('/',(req, res) => {
    console.log("REQ PARAMS: ");
    console.log(req.params);
    console.log("REQ BODY: ");
    console.log(req.body);
    console.log("REQ JSON: ");
    console.log(JSON.stringify(req.body));
    const sender = req.body.sender;
    const recipient = req.body.recipient;

    console.log(sender);
    console.log(recipient);

    res.json({success: true});
});


module.exports = router;
```

This is deployed on Heroku and I get follwoing output when mailgun hits the route:

```
2019-10-03T09:29:39.558514+00:00 app[web.1]: REQ PARAMS:
2019-10-03T09:29:39.558515+00:00 app[web.1]: {}
2019-10-03T09:29:39.558516+00:00 app[web.1]: REQ BODY:
2019-10-03T09:29:39.558518+00:00 app[web.1]: {}
2019-10-03T09:29:39.558519+00:00 app[web.1]: REQ JSON:
2019-10-03T09:29:39.558521+00:00 app[web.1]: {}
2019-10-03T09:29:39.558522+00:00 app[web.1]: undefined
2019-10-03T09:29:39.558524+00:00 app[web.1]: undefined
```

I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong, so I'm glad for any help!

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that I was using the `body-parser` middleware instead of

`app.use(express.urlencoded());`

My bad...